# How to fix VT-x/AMD-V error in the AMD Ryzen 3 2000G Bios

Tags: hardware, bios

This issue is posted several times in similar way, but no answers seen yet. Has anybody a good idea if the mentioned Bios is able to be set to hardware excellaration?

Comment: Hello, Heinz! How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: installing Ubuntu 64k requires a hardware excelleration in VMware. This must be set in the Bios, otherwise the installation fails

Comment: This seems like a great question for the motherboard manufacturer. Ubuntu has nothing to do with the BIOS setting that you are asking about.

Comment: I thought ao myself, but did not get excitement with my question at ASUS, so I tried here hoping that others might have tried the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no CPU BIOS, but your computer BIOS instead. All major newer CPUs have VT-X/AMD-V support. As you start your computer, press DEL, F2, F10, F12 or the correct key, which is displayed as you start it. As you navigate through the menus, you'll find the option. Just activate it (usually, it is inside the "Advanced" one) and you should be good to go.

But this seems odd to me, these technologies are for virtualization, like VirtualBox, VMWare, Xen, KVM and such, and should not be required to install the operating system itself.

Comment: sorry but you are wrong. Yes I want to install Ubuntu 64, in VMbox since Ubuntu 32 bit is not supported anymore. This requires that in the board BIOS VT x/AMD-V support is turned on. Board manufacturer ASUS is just not willing to help. This problem is existing in many forum, but without any answer. This is the reason that I was so brave to raise the question here in the hope that anyone may have tried similar installations. Sorry to disturb the silence here.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're trying to install it on a virtualized environment. As I told you before, it's not hard to enable VT-x/AMD-V. Checkout your motherboard's manual and see how to access your BIOS setup and how to enable it.

Best regards.